# Import raw data into R

Tags: r, import, read.table

please anyone can help me to import this data into R from a text or dat file. It has space delimited, but cities names should not considered as two names. Like NEW YORK.

```
1 NEW YORK  7,262,700
2 LOS ANGELES  3,259,340
3 CHICAGO  3,009,530
4 HOUSTON  1,728,910
5 PHILADELPHIA  1,642,900
6 DETROIT  1,086,220
7 SAN DIEGO  1,015,190
8 DALLAS  1,003,520
9 SAN ANTONIO  914,350
10 PHOENIX  894,070
```

Answer (score 4):

For your particular data frame, where true spaces only occur between capital letters, consider using a regular expression:

```
gsub("(*[A-Z]) ([A-Z]+)", "\\1-\\2", "1 NEW YORK  7,262,700")
# [1] "1 NEW-YORK 7,262,700"
gsub("(*[A-Z]) ([A-Z]+)", "\\1-\\2", "3 CHICAGO  3,009,530")
# [1] "3 CHICAGO  3,009,530"
```

You can then interpret spaces as field separators.

Comment: The second `[A-Z]` should be followed by a `+` not a `*`, otherwise you end up with `CHICAGO-` for one word cities.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on a theme... but first, some sample data:

```
cat("1 NEW YORK  7,262,700",
    "2 LOS ANGELES  3,259,340",
    "3 CHICAGO  3,009,530",
    "4 HOUSTON  1,728,910",
    "5 PHILADELPHIA  1,642,900",
    "6 DETROIT  1,086,220",
    "7 SAN DIEGO  1,015,190",
    "8 DALLAS  1,003,520",
    "9 SAN ANTONIO  914,350",
    "10 PHOENIX  894,070", sep = "\n", file = "test.txt")
```

***Step 1***: Read the data in with `readLines`

```
x <- readLines("test.txt")
```

***Step 2***: Figure out a regular expression that you can use to insert delimiters. Here, the pattern seems to be (looking from the *end* of the lines) a set of numbers and commas preceded by space preceded by some words in ALL CAPS. We can capture those groups and insert some "tab" delimiters (`\t`). The extra slashes are to properly escape them.

```
gsub("([A-Z ]+)(\\s?[0-9,]+$)", "\\\t\\1\\\t\\2", x)
#  [1] "1\t NEW YORK  \t7,262,700"     "2\t LOS ANGELES  \t3,259,340" 
#  [3] "3\t CHICAGO  \t3,009,530"      "4\t HOUSTON  \t1,728,910"     
#  [5] "5\t PHILADELPHIA  \t1,642,900" "6\t DETROIT  \t1,086,220"     
#  [7] "7\t SAN DIEGO  \t1,015,190"    "8\t DALLAS  \t1,003,520"      
#  [9] "9\t SAN ANTONIO  \t914,350"    "10\t PHOENIX  \t894,070"
```

***Step 3***: Since we know our `gsub` is working, and we know that `read.delim` has a "`text`" argument that can be used instead of a "`file`" argument, we can use `read.delim` directly on the result of `gsub`:

```
out <- read.delim(text = gsub("([A-Z ]+)(\\s?[0-9,]+$)", "\\\t\\1\\\t\\2", x), 
                  header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
out
#    V1           V2        V3
# 1   1     NEW YORK 7,262,700
# 2   2  LOS ANGELES 3,259,340
# 3   3      CHICAGO 3,009,530
# 4   4      HOUSTON 1,728,910
# 5   5 PHILADELPHIA 1,642,900
# 6   6      DETROIT 1,086,220
# 7   7    SAN DIEGO 1,015,190
# 8   8       DALLAS 1,003,520
# 9   9  SAN ANTONIO   914,350
# 10 10      PHOENIX   894,070
```

One possible last step would be to convert the third column to numeric:

```
out$V3 <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", out$V3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Hugh's answer I would try the following, although its not particularly efficient.

```
lines <- scan("cities.txt", sep="\n", what="character")
lines <- unlist(lapply(lines, function(x) { 
  gsub(pattern="(*[a-zA-Z]) ([a-zA-Z]+)", replacement="\\1-\\2", x) 
}))

citiesDF <- data.frame(num  = rep(0, length(lines)), 
                       city = rep("", length(lines)), 
                       population = rep(0, length(lines)),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(lines)) {
   splitted = strsplit(lines[i], " +")
   citiesDF[i, "num"] <- as.numeric(splitted[[1]][1])
   citiesDF[i, "city"] <- gsub("-", " ", splitted[[1]][2])
   citiesDF[i, "population"] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", splitted[[1]][3]))
}
```