# Reading non-uniform data into R

Tags: r

I struggling with reading non-uniform data into R.

I've achieved the following:

- Used "readLines" to read the text file data in
- Used "grep" to find the block of data that I want
- Used the index from grep to create a variable (named "block") that contains only that block of data

All good so far - I now have the data I want. But - its a character variable with only one column that contains all the data.

This creates a sample of the variable I have made called "block" (first 3 rows):

```
line1 = c("    114.24    -0.39     0.06    13.85     -0.06     1402.11      -1.48     0.0003     0.0000      35.468      1.02    -0.02     0.00   0   1   1   1     0    49.87   4      -290         0         0     -0.002     -0.010      0.155    999.00   11482.66    999.00   11482.66  16:52:24:119          255     13.89     50.00     0.00    -5.49    0.00")
line2 = c("    114.28    -0.39     0.08    13.84     -0.06     1402.57      -1.48     0.0004     0.0000      35.479      1.29    -0.02     0.00   0   1   1   1     0    49.82   4      -272         0         0     -0.002     -0.011      0.124    999.00   11482.66    999.00   11482.66  16:52:24:150          255     13.89     50.00     0.00    -5.49    0.00")
line3 = c("    114.31    -0.39     0.09    13.83     -0.06     1403.03      -1.47     0.0005     0.0000      35.492      1.42    -0.02     0.00   0   1   1   1     0    49.78   4      -263         0         0     -0.002     -0.011      0.046    999.00   11482.66    999.00   11482.66  16:52:24:197          255     13.89     50.00     0.00    -5.49    0.00")

block = c(line1,line2,line3)
```

My goal is to have this data as a data.frame with separate columns for each data point.

My attempts at using strsplit haven't helped (does the solution involve strsplit?)- what is the best approach here? Any suggestions/feedback welcome.

strsplit(block,"\s",fixed=F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following should work for you:

```
## Creates a "data.table"
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data.table(x = block), "x", " ")

## Creates a "data.frame"
read.table(text = block, header = FALSE)

## Creates a character matrix
do.call(rbind, strsplit(block, "\\s+"))

## Like the above, but likely to be faster
library(stringi)
stri_split_regex(block, "\\s+", simplify = TRUE)
```

Note the `"\\s+"` for the last two options. The "+" is to match multiple spaces.

Comment: A big thank you! The "read.table" solution is perfect. Thanks for taking the time to post. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Actually - this looks like it might work.

[Import raw data into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941150/import-raw-data-into-r)

But wanted to check if this was the best approach to this situation...?